# Populate Textbox with ID column of related selected value from Combo Box

Tags: c#, winforms, list, combobox, textbox

Hi I'm having trouble displaying my data in win forms. I have a sql database which I put the table in a list:

```
  public List<ItemsForSale> GetStock()
        {
            var db = new Model1();
            return db.Stock.ToList();
        }
```

I populate my Combo box with the selected value but only show one of the columns (stock name) other columns are stock amount and stock price.

```
   Stock stock = new Stock();

   comboBox1.DataSource = stock.GetStock().Select(x => x.StockName).ToList();
```

How can I display the rows data in other text boxes. For example if I select the stock Pasta how can I display it's price in a text box.

Comment: Do you know about events of controls? Where do you stuck?

Comment: @Sinatr The only event control I have used is on the form onload to populate the combo box. Is there a event that I can use to do this?

Comment: *"Is there a event"* - [yep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example, You are looking for combobox's `selectedIndex_Changed` event.

I have a `Stock` entity,

```
public class Stock {
       public Stock(int Id,string Name,decimal Price) {
           this.Id = Id;
           this.Name = Name;
           this.Price = Price;
       }
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public decimal Price { get; set; }
}


List<Stock> dataSource = new List<Stock>(); // set list of object to an variable not to query db again and again, just use this all the time
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      dataSource = GetStocks(); 
      comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"; // set display member
      comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id"; // value member as Id to use at selectedIndex changed
      comboBox1.DataSource = dataSource;
}
public List<Stock> GetStocks() { // just creating on my own list, you won't change this
     return new List<Stock>() { new Stock(1,"test1",13) , new Stock(2, "test2", 17), new Stock(3, "test3", 113) };
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     // query your List variable to find the stock by selected Item's Id, get first one and take Price property
      decimal value = dataSource.Where(x => x.Id == (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue).FirstOrDefault().Price; 
      textBox1.Text = value.ToString(); // set value to textbox
}
```

Hope helps,

Comment: Just progressing on this, how would I populate textbox2 with the stock amount. I have tried repeating the part in SelectedIndexChanged but my result doesn't show

Comment: `Stock value = dataSource.Where(x => x.Id == (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue).FirstOrDefault();`
`textBox1.Text = value.Price.ToString();`
`textBox2.Text = value.AnotherProperty.ToString();` @Phil3992